# Subscript alignment of quantifiers in Latex

Tags: subscripts, subequations

I would like to align the some subequations vertically, so that they look nice, something like this:[image: vertically algned equations]

Here's a MWE with my approach so far:

```
%! Author = scrooge
%! Date = 09.12.21

% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\foralllimits}[1]{\mathop{\forall} \limits_{#1}}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{alignat}{2}
            &\foralllimits{x\ \in\ \left[-5; -\frac{2}{3} \right]}\ &&g_{1} (x) =  2\\
            &\foralllimits{x\ \in\ \left[-\frac{2}{3}; 0 \right]}\ &&g_{1} (x) = -3x\\
            &\foralllimits{x\ \in\ \left[0; \frac{2}{3} \right]}\ &&g_{1} (x) = 3x\\
            &\foralllimits{x\ \in\ \left[\frac{2}{3}; 5 \right]}\ &&g_{1} (x) = 2
        \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

I have defined the command `\foralllimits` like this: `\newcommand{\foralllimits}[1]{\mathop{\forall} \limits_{#1}}` which serves the purpose of printing a "for all" quantifier and underneath it the variables to which the quantifier refers. Does this follow LaTeX conventions?

Ideally, I would like the subscripts of the quantifiers to also be vertically aligned regarding the "element of" symbol, like this (Note how the Element symbol is always directly under the quantifier):

[image: other vertically algned equations]

How could I accomplish that?

**TL; DR**

What's convention conform best way to vertically align subscripts of quantifiers in a multi-equation system in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: I have added a MWE. I hope this helps.

Comment: @TeeGeeVee: Asking whether something is "a good way to do [it]?" leaves the question open to suggestive/personal opinion answers. *You* should define what is good instead and rather request how to achieve *your* goal.

Comment: With "good way to do it" I mean according to LaTeX conventions, not using any deprecated stuff or something like pure TeX commands in a LaTeX document. How could I reword my question so the intention becomes clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but you could make a `\phantom` of your longest subscript and then use `\mathrlap` to overlap the visible text with the phantom text.

[image]

Note that `\mathrlap` requires the `mathtools` package (which replaces `amsmath`). I also replaced your `\newcommand` with `\DeclareMathOperator*`. (The star places the limits below the symbol in `displaystyle`.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\foralllimits}{\forall}
%\newcommand{\foralllimits}[1]{\mathop{\forall} \limits_{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{alignat}{2}
            &\foralllimits_{x\ \in\ \left[-5; -\frac{2}{3} \right]}\ &&g_{1} (x) =  2\\
            &\foralllimits_{x\ \in\ \mathrlap{\left[-\frac{2}{3}; 0 \right]}\phantom{\left[-5; -\frac{2}{3} \right]}}\ &&g_{1} (x) = -3x\\
            &\foralllimits_{x\ \in\ \mathrlap{\left[0; \frac{2}{3} \right]}\phantom{\left[-5; -\frac{2}{3} \right]}}\ &&g_{1} (x) = 3x\\
            &\foralllimits_{x\ \in\ \mathrlap{\left[\frac{2}{3}; 5 \right]}\phantom{\left[-5; -\frac{2}{3} \right]}}\ &&g_{1} (x) = 2
        \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

But I would be more inclined to use `cases`, or, if you want the individual lines labeled, the `cases` package with `subnumcases`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}   

    \begin{subnumcases}{g_1(x)=}
        \phantom{-x}2 & $\forall x\in[-5; -\tfrac{2}{3}]$\\
        -3x & $\forall x\in[-\tfrac{2}{3}; 0]$\\
        \phantom{-}3x & $\forall x\in[0; \tfrac{2}{3}]$\\
        \phantom{-x}2 & $\forall x\in[\tfrac{2}{3}; 5]$
    \end{subnumcases} 
    
\end{document}
```

You can get rid of the `\phantom{-x}` if you like that look better.

Comment: Your first example goes kind of in the direction I mean, but I would also like the "element of" symbol to be directly centered under the quantifier in the subscript. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use that display for defining a function by cases. You *can*, though.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\foralllimits}[1]{\mathop{\underset{#1}{\forall}}\relax}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[3][c]{\eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$\displaystyle#3$}}
\newcommand{\eqforalllimits}[2]{%
  \eqmathbox{#1}{\foralllimits{#2}}%
}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \eqforalllimits{A}{x\in \bigl[-5; -\frac{2}{3}\bigr]} &\;& g_{1} (x) &=  2\\
  \eqforalllimits{A}{x\in \bigl[-\frac{2}{3}; 0\bigr]}  &&   g_{1} (x) &= -3x\\
  \eqforalllimits{A}{x\in \bigl[0; \frac{2}{3}\bigr]}   &&   g_{1} (x) &= 3x\\
  \eqforalllimits{A}{x\in \bigl[\frac{2}{3}; 5\bigr]}   &&   g_{1} (x) &= 2
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different rendering (without “forall” that doesn't really fit mathematically):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}


% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\setlength{\jot}{6pt}
\begin{empheq}[left={g_1(x)=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
2   &\qquad& x &\in \bigl[-5; -\tfrac{2}{3}\bigr] \\
-3x &\qquad& x &\in \bigl[-\tfrac{2}{3}; 0\bigr] \\
3x  &\qquad& x &\in \bigl[0; \tfrac{2}{3}\bigr] \\
2   &\qquad& x &\in \bigl[\tfrac{2}{3}; 5\bigr]
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How could I center the "Element of" Symbol under the quantifier in your first example?

Comment: @TeeGeeVee Sorry, but that would be even worse.

Comment: Could you explain why this would be bad/worse style? Just because you generally don't write something like this or because some part of it makes it unreadable?

Comment: @TeeGeeVee That's of course a matter of opinion; if you think to it, you'll clearly see that the thing would be very unbalanced when the two parts around `\in` have very different width, like in the present case. My principle is “never try to align things that are unrelated to each other”.